# Помогите абсолютному новичку

Tags: python

Вот код:

```
with open('1.txt') as f:
    n = int(f.readline())
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = map(int, f.readline().split())
        print(a,b)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/linar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/1234.py", line 4, in <module>
    a, b = map(int, f.readline().split()) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Сам файл ТХТ:

```
25
42214 2493
37650 0594
593903 494
93827 4756
204847 94930
438943876 292
3485 239084
42214 2493
37650 0594
593903 494
93827 4756
204847 94930
438943876 292
3485 239084
42214 2493
37650 0594
593903 494
93827 4756
204847 94930
438943876 292
3485 239084
382394 2480932
```

Comment: Ответ в ошибке которую он вам дал.

Comment: очень позновательно

Comment: Вы читает 25 пар значений из файла в в котором только 22 пары значений. Данных не хватает. И именно это и говорится в ошибке (забавное совпадение).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
with open('1.txt') as f:
    n = int(f.readline())
    for i in range(n - 3):
        a, b = map(int, f.readline().split())
        print(a, b)
```

Comment: Все четко, без ошибок. А можно поподробнее?

Comment: Если вывести переменную ```n = int(f.readline())``` то мы увидим число 25, несмотря на то что всего строчек 22, проведя логические рассуждения от ```n``` отнимаем 3)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```py
with open('1.txt') as f:
    n = int(f.readline())
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = map(int, n.split())
        print(a,b)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: а что ты хочешь получить на выходе?

Comment: Чтобы не было ошибки)